# Using wkhtmltopdf with highcharts shows blank chart

Tags: highcharts, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I'm attempting to use wkhtmltopdf via Rotativa to convert a basic html page which uses jquery and highcharts to render a demo chart. The chart renders correctly when displayed in a browser. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? This code results in a blank PDF.

My view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Highcharts Test</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style type="text/css">
        #chart { float:left; width:300px; height:300px; }
    </style>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#chart').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    backgroundColor: "red"  
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Tokyo',
                    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                }, {
                    name: 'New York',
                    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
                }, {
                    name: 'Berlin',
                    data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
                }, {
                    name: 'London',
                    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Rotativa;

namespace Completions.MvcApplication.Controllers.Pages
{
public class ReportsController : BasePageController
{
    public ActionResult Systems()
    {
        return new ViewAsPdf();
    } 
}
}
```

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Have you tried to use included exporitng module ? exporing.js

Comment: Can you share a link to the page so we can test?

Comment: I don't have it hosted anywhere as of yet, so I can't provide a link. The test page in this case renders just a blank PDF. If I add other non-chart content, only chart is missing.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160340 this; did it help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wkhtmltopdf fails to printing SVG path (highchart)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160340/wkhtmltopdf-fails-to-printing-svg-path-highchart)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and the cause was JavaScript errors. You can confirm this by running wkhtmltopdf with the `--debug-javascript` flag. For more detailed debugging (e.g. line numbers) you'll have to download the [QtWeb browser](http://qtweb.net/download.php).

Specifically in my case the two issues were that `Object.values(obj)` is an undefined function and `$('a:not(.ignore)')` is a syntax error (when jQuery 3.1.1 tried to use the selector). The fix was to use `Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key] })` and `$('a').not('.ignore')`.

Answer (score 2):

To me it seemed to me that the graph would stop rendering midway through. So what worked for me was setting the animation off:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: false
    }
}
```

This way the chart is ready once the pdf is generated.