# Could not make Highcharts display in pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am trying to export a html page to pdf in ruby on rails application. The html page has highcharts, tables and images. I am using wkhtmltopdf and highcharts.

Gemfile

```
gem "highcharts-rails"
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge'
```

export_pdf.html.erb

```
<div id="container"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

 Highcharts.chart('container', {

   title: {
       text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
   },

   subtitle: {
       text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
   },

   yAxis: {
       title: {
           text: 'Number of Employees'
       }
   },
   legend: {
       layout: 'vertical',
       align: 'right',
       verticalAlign: 'middle'
   },
plotOptions: {
                 line: {
                   marker: {
                     enabled: false
                   },
                   dashStyle: 'ShortDash'
                 },
                 series: { enableMouseTracking: false, shadow: false, animation: false } 
               },

   series: [{
       name: 'Installation',
       data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
   }, {
       name: 'Manufacturing',
       data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
   }, {
       name: 'Sales & Distribution',
       data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
   }, {
       name: 'Project Development',
       data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
   }, {
       name: 'Other',
       data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
   }],

   responsive: {
       rules: [{
           condition: {
               maxWidth: 500
           },
           chartOptions: {
               legend: {
                   layout: 'horizontal',
                   align: 'center',
                   verticalAlign: 'bottom'
               }
           }
       }]
   }

});
</script>
```

app/views/layouts/pdf.html.erb

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PDF</title>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" -%>
</head>
<body> <div class='container'>
<%= yield %>
</div></body>
</html>
```

reports_controller.rb

```
def export_pdf
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: "your_assessment_printout.pdf",
      disposition: "inline",
      template: "reports/export_pdf.html.erb",
      layout: "pdf.html.erb",
      :disable_javascript   => false,
      javascript_delay: 1000
    end
    format.html
  end
end
```

Am using,

```
ruby 2.3.0
rails 5.1.1
```

Charts display well in html page, but in pdf it is not displaying. Other contents like tables and images are displaying in pdf. Please comment if need to post more details on this.

Comment: Hi @poombavai, Have you tried to disable chart and series animation?

Comment: yes. Disabled series animation. But how to disable chart and why should we need that? @ppotaczek

Comment: I mean chart animation and series animation. We need that to prevent asynch chart loading.

Comment: @ppotaczek Tried. Not working.

Comment: Please also check these two threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160340/wkhtmltopdf-fails-to-printing-svg-path-highchart, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106434/using-wkhtmltopdf-with-highcharts-shows-blank-chart

Comment: @poombavai Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @poombavai, did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include **highcharts** js in the PDF layout. Add **highcharts** js to PDF layout.

```
# app/views/layouts/pdf.html.erb
<head>
  ..
  <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'highcharts' %>
  ..
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

So We are using WickedPdf's pdf_from_string() on an HTML page generated with render_to_string() with a javascript delay to ensure that the charts have been rendered.

```
def export_pdf
    format.pdf do
      pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        render_to_string('reports/export_pdf.html.erb',
          :layout => 'layouts/pdf.html',
          :javascript_delay => 5000),
      )
      send_data pdf, filename: "#{@report.name}.pdf",
            type: 'application/pdf',
            disposition: 'inline'
end
```

Comment: Tried this. No luck @sam