# Highcharts pattern plugin and wkhtmltopdf

Tags: design-patterns, svg, highcharts, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using HighCharts Pattern Fill plugin http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill. Everything works fine, but when used with wkhtmltopdf, the area, that suppose to be filled with pattern is blank.

Did anyone had similar issue? Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I advice to familair with similar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160340/wkhtmltopdf-fails-to-printing-svg-path-highchart

Answer (score 0):

Since there are not answers yet, try this:

```
wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 6000 http://yoururl.com derp.pdf
```

Increasing the delay might work I mean. If this still fails, try with 60000. If that fails... :/